# zxing focus on iOS

Tags: ios, zxing

I might be missing something here but it seems that zxing does not support auto-focus. Having done some searches here and on Google I haven't found anything that gives any insight.

E.g. on my iPhone 4 using the sample ScanTest app many of the QR codes are blurry and tricky for the app to recognise.

So, to be a bit more specific:
Does zxing support auto-focus on the iPhone and, if so, how do you implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm ... the camera autofocuses on its own on hardware that is not fixed-focus, unless told to do otherwise, I believe. I think it's possible to do a tap-to-focus thing but zxing doesn't do that.

Comment: How do you do tap-to-focus?

Comment: First Google result for "ios sdk tap to focus" is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919485/ios-5-avcapturedevice-setting-focus-point-and-focus-mode-freezes-the-live-came but you'll have to figure out how to integrate that into zxing.